# SIFT feature extractor

Tags: opencv, image-processing, classification, sift

Which one is the feature in SIFT .Is key Point or descriptor .I am trying to cluster .which one should I consider for clustering and why?. This cluster data is used for classification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The descriptor is what you mean by "feature". Keep in mind that a SIFT descriptor is made of 128 int elements, which will make your classifying task really hard (from a computational point of view) unless using some kind of dimensional reduction

Comment: The classification of SIFTs is not hard, "bag of visual words" model uses it and it is common technique.

Comment: Bag of visual words, in its original version, is NP-hard.

Comment: Keypoint is a vector of four elements representing location (x,y), scale and orientation of your descriptor. The descriptor itself is a vector of 128 elements describing "histograms of local gradients", in a way which is invariabt to scale and rotation, and robust against noise and illumination. Lowe's paper can be a bit difficult to read without some math prerequirements, but it can be really enlightening

Comment: how clustering done on this 128 int element.I have set of image

Comment: Try reading "bag of visual words" as suggested on top... In fact, how to cluster your data depends from the usage they're intended for...